# Jenkins start build, then wait for choices input before continuing build

Tags: jenkins, build, parameters, ansible

I have a Jenkins Pipeline contained in a script that dynamically builds dropdown menus for input parameters that get used later in subsequent steps. The first time I run the build it creates the dropdowns but doesn't display them to the user, it just continues on to the next step using the default inputs.

If I then run the build a second time it displays the dropdowns and waits for choice selection by the user before continuing on to the next step. How do I get the dropdowns to display and wait on the first run as well?

Here is a pic of the dropdowns the second time I run the build:

[image: ansiblePipeline1]

Here is my Pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

    stage ('Build Parameters') {
      steps {
        script {

            properties([
                parameters([

                      choice(
                        choices: [ 'MyEsxiServer.esxi' ],
                                  description: 'On which ESXi Server should this script run?',
                                  name: 'esxiServer'
                      ),
                      choice(
                        choices: [ 'dev','stage','prod' ],
                                  description: 'In which environment should this script run?',
                                  name: 'environment'
                      ),

                    [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
                        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
                        description: 'On which runner should this script run?',
                        filterLength: 1,
                        filterable: false,
                        name: 'runner',
                        randomName: 'choice-parameter-596645940283131',
                        script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                            script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false,
                                script:
'''// Build choices for runner drop down
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

log = new File('/tmp/groovy.log')

// execute the OS cmd and return the results
def sout = new StringBuilder()
def serr = new StringBuilder() //standard out and error strings

//Assemble command
def cmd = "/home/jenkins/bpb/testautomation/ansible/playbooks/listVMs.sh"
log.append("\\ncmd: " + cmd + "\\n") //debug

//Execute OS command
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(sout, serr) //Wait for command to complete
proc.waitForOrKill(10000) //Set timeout
log.append("sout: " + sout + "\\n") //debug
log.append("serr: " + serr + "\\n") //debug

// translate JSON to List
def soutList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(sout.toString())
log.append("soutList: " + soutList + "\\n") //debug

def List vmList = soutList.vms.sort()
log.append("vmList: " + vmList + "\\n") //debug

return vmList
'''
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],

                    choice(
                        choices: [ 'CentOS51','Comodore64','BeOS' ],
                                  description: 'What is the target Operating System?',
                                  name: 'targetOS'
                    )

                ]) //parameters
            ]) //properties

        } //script
      } //steps
    } //stage

    stage ('Execute Ansible') {
          steps {
            ansiblePlaybook credentialsId: 'b7a24821-8dc3-40d0-8cee-ef284e07393a',
              disableHostKeyChecking: true,
              colorized: true,
              installation: 'Ansible',
              inventory: "testautomation/ansible/${params.environment}/${params.environment}.inv",
              playbook: 'testautomation/ansible/playbooks/run_cmd_inside_vm.yml',
              extras: "-v -e runner=${params.runner} -e shell_cmd=/home/kcason/Desktop/${params.targetOS}/3-run.sh"
          } //steps
    } //stage

  } // stages
} // pipeline
```

Answer (score 1):

Not at all sadly. You can start a job with or without parameters (depending on how it is configured). The properties call changes this configuration but only after the job is started (without parameters/ with the old parameters). Jenkins cannot do that before since the properties call could be anywhere in the script and could depend on steps before it.

This article https://dev.to/pencillr/jenkins-pipelines-and-their-dirty-secrets-1 discusses this topic in more detail.

Also see the open issue in the jenkins issue tracker https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-41929

Comment: Wow, that is the best documentation I've seen so far for parameterized jobs! Thank you so much. :-)